# Using Python to download .xlsx file from Microsoft Forms

Tags: python, forms

I'm working on an intake form using *Microsoft Forms*. How do I download the `.xlsx` file from the response page using Python?

Comment: what have you tried already? not a single line of code?

Comment: I have tried looking at the source code for a download link, and I tried to set up Selenium, but I was running into trouble. The excel file is only able to be downloaded through the click of a button it seems, and I'm running into trouble with clicking the button.

Comment: from selenium import webdriver ###  

driver = webdriver.Chrome() ###  
driver.get("web_page") ###  
button = driver.find_element_by_id('Open in Excel') ###  
button.click() ####